# Sending a JPEG over a socket only sends a tiny portion of the image

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am following a basic networking course and one I reached a challenge where it asks to make both a server and a client that can transfer information with commands, I had no problems with the more basic commands but I'm having troubles sending a JPEG image, my way of approaching it is taking a screenshot using the PILLOW module, then opening it with binary read attribute, then basically sending the binary data over the socket, and writing the binary data into a new jpeg file, the result is a JPEG that shows up the top left corner of the screenshot correct but then it goes blank, like the binary information is cut after the first few lines.

How it's supposed to work: If you insert the string 'SCS' as the client input, the server is supposed to take a screenshot and send it to the client over the socket.

This is my code:

Server:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket, os


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket()

    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8820))

    server_socket.listen(1)

    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()

    data = client_socket.recv(1024)

    if data == 'SCS':
        ImageGrab.grab().save('screenshot', 'JPEG') #Take a screenshot and save it on CWD.
        file = open(os.getcwd()+'//'+ 'screenshot', 'rb') #Open the screenshot with Read Binary attribute
        client_socket.send(file.read()) #Send the binary data over the socket



    client_socket.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
import socket, os


clientsocket = socket.socket()

clientsocket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8820))

input = raw_input('Enter command: ')

clientsocket.send(input)

data = clientsocket.recv(1024) #Recieve binary data of the screenshot

file = open('image.jpg', 'wb')  #create a blank jpeg file
file.write(data) #write binary information to blank jpeg file
file.close()  #close file

print data

print('file saved to ' + os.getcwd())

clientsocket.close()
```

Comment: You only read the first 1024 bytes of the image; keep reading until there is no more data. Or you could pack and send the size of the image before the image data, so that the client will know exactly how many bytes to read.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so ```file.read()``` only reads 1024 bytes at a time? so I basically need to loop it till there's no more information?

Comment: No, `file.read()` reads all the data, but your socket client only receives 1024 (`data = clientsocket.recv(1024)`). So, it is the client that would read in a loop.

Comment: Oh wow! I was so sure the problem was in the file handling that I completely overlooked that line! thank you, submit this is as an answer and I'll be sure to mark it.

Comment: Sorry, I won't post an answer, but if you think it may help others you could submit your answer and accept it. Cheers!